# How to produce json response that consumes json object using spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting 415 Error.
This is my mapping used for getting the json response

```
@RequestMapping(value="/details", method= RequestMethod.POST ,
        consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE ,
        produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<UserDetails> addUserDetails(@RequestBody 
                RegisterInput registerInput)throws ValidationException{

    if(registerInput==null || registerInput.getUserName()==null){
                throw new ValidationException("Input is not valid");
    }
    UserDetails userDetails=new UserDetails(registerInput.getUserName(),
                    registerInput.getFirstName(), registerInput.getLastName(), registerInput.getPassword());
    userDetailsService.addUserDetails(userDetails);
    return new ResponseEntity<UserDetails>(userDetails, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Help me with how to get the json response as it says error 415 in my case.
Thanks in advance

where UserDetails is the POJO class and RegisterInput is to store the input and return json object. The following is my pom.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your method to return the response directly to response body via `@ResponseBody`

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/details", method= RequestMethod.POST ,
            consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE ,
            produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   @ResponseBody public UserDetails addUserDetails(@RequestBody 
                                        RegisterInput registerInput)throws ValidationException{

        if(registerInput==null || registerInput.getUserName()==null){
           throw new ValidationException("Input is not valid");
         }
         UserDetails userDetails=new userDetails(registerInput.getUserName(),
                        registerInput.getFirstName(), registerInput.getLastName(), registerInput.getPassword());
          userDetailsService.addUserDetails(userDetails);
          return userDetails;
   }
```

note also that you need jackson 2.x dependencies only if you're using spring 4

*OR*

jackson 1.9.x only if your using Spring 3.x.x

Comment: post the code of your bean, there are two common factors that hinder conversion, missing or wrong dependencies, or bad POJO in a sense of erroneus getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controller annotated with [`@RestController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) (instead of with the classic `@Controller`).

This way, you're telling Spring to use the object you are returning as your response's body.

Make sure you are sending both `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers with `application/json` and that the Json you're sending is well-formed.

Comment: It still throws the same error. Error 415, media unsupported

Comment: @Dilpreet are you sending Accept header with application/json?

Answer (score 0):

You need make your post data to your url is json. I in doubt you post data is wrong. [This post](http://devjav.com/restful-application-with-spring-mvc/) also good example Spring rest using @Controller and @ResponseBody

Comment: I am using Hibernate in which I need to access data from database. So I want to consume json object dynamically that gets stored in my database

Comment: you still can do that, the example just demo but you can see other example that store object to database using hibernate on that site

Answer (score 0):

You can get JSON as response back via setting

> ResponseEntity

as return type of your method in controller class. You can also add additional json key value pair via creating **Map** lets see the below example;

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteDepartment(@PathVariable Long id) throws NotFoundException {


    Optional<Department> department = this.departmentService.findADepartment(id);
    if (department == null)
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();

    Map<String, String> stringStringMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (departmentService.deleteADepartment(id)) {
        stringStringMap.put("status", "success");
        stringStringMap.put("message", "successfully deleted");
        stringStringMap.put("code", "200");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).
                body(stringStringMap);

    } else {
        stringStringMap.put("status", "failed");
        stringStringMap.put("message", "not  deleted");
        stringStringMap.put("code", "404");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).
                body(stringStringMap);

    }

}
```

Here Input URL is

`http://localhost:8080/department/delete/7`

And Output Response is

```
{
"code": "200",
"message": "successfully deleted",
"status": "success"
}
```